# Multiple arguments of a function not working with std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to create a thread of a function but I'm getting errors. Calling the function without making a thread works fine.

```
thread t (moveAliens, aliens, alienX, alienY, aslp );
t.join();
```

The function:

```
void moveAliens ( CircleShape aliens[], float& alienX, float& alienY, Time& aslp ){
    aliens[0].setPosition(Vector2f(alienX, alienY));
    aliens[1].setPosition(Vector2f(alienX+100, alienY));
    aliens[2].setPosition(Vector2f(alienX+200, alienY));
    aliens[3].setPosition(Vector2f(alienX+300, alienY));
    aliens[4].setPosition(Vector2f(alienX+400, alienY));
    aliens[5].setPosition(Vector2f(alienX+500, alienY));
    aliens[6].setPosition(Vector2f(alienX+600, alienY));
    aliens[7].setPosition(Vector2f(alienX, alienY+50));
    aliens[8].setPosition(Vector2f(alienX+100, alienY+50));
    aliens[9].setPosition(Vector2f(alienX+200, alienY+50));
    aliens[10].setPosition(Vector2f(alienX+300, alienY+50));
    aliens[11].setPosition(Vector2f(alienX+400, alienY+50));
    aliens[12].setPosition(Vector2f(alienX+500, alienY+50));
    aliens[13].setPosition(Vector2f(alienX+600, alienY+50));
    alienX += 50;
    sleep(aslp);
    cout << "The value of alienX is " << alienX << " and the value of alienY is " << alienY << endl;
    if ( aliens[6].getPosition().x >= 750 ){
        alienX = 20;
        alienY += 50;
    }
    if ( aliens[13].getPosition().y > 450 ){
        alienY = 50;
        alienX = 20;
    }
}
```

All the passed objects/variables are declared in main.

```
float alienX = 50, alienY = 20, fireY = 0;
CircleShape aliens[40];
Time aslp = milliseconds(200);
```

The error code:

```
> Executing task: g++ '/home/r2fpdvzocm5ydw/Documents/CPP Programs/PF Project/main.cpp' -o game -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system && ./game <

In file included from /home/r2fpdvzocm5ydw/Documents/CPP Programs/PF Project/main.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/9.2.0/thread: In instantiation of ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(sf::CircleShape*, float&, float&, sf::Time&); _Args = {sf::CircleShape (&)[40], float&, float&, sf::Time&}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]’:
/home/r2fpdvzocm5ydw/Documents/CPP Programs/PF Project/main.cpp:88:60:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9.2.0/thread:120:44: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
  120 |           typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
      |                                            ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9.2.0/thread: In instantiation of ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(sf::CircleShape*, float&, float&, sf::Time&), sf::CircleShape*, float, float, sf::Time> >’:
/usr/include/c++/9.2.0/thread:131:22:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(sf::CircleShape*, float&, float&, sf::Time&); _Args = {sf::CircleShape (&)[40], float&, float&, sf::Time&}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]’
/home/r2fpdvzocm5ydw/Documents/CPP Programs/PF Project/main.cpp:88:60:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9.2.0/thread:243:4: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(sf::CircleShape*, float&, float&, sf::Time&), sf::CircleShape*, float, float, sf::Time> >::__result<std::tuple<void (*)(sf::CircleShape*, float&, float&, sf::Time&), sf::CircleShape*, float, float, sf::Time> >’
  243 |    _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Ind...>)
      |    ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9.2.0/thread:247:2: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(sf::CircleShape*, float&, float&, sf::Time&), sf::CircleShape*, float, float, sf::Time> >::__result<std::tuple<void (*)(sf::CircleShape*, float&, float&, sf::Time&), sf::CircleShape*, float, float, sf::Time> >’
  247 |  operator()()
      |  ^~~~~~~~
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Writing more as stackoverflow says more details than code.
I'm using SFML library and want to create a separate thread for movement of aliens (red circles).
I'm calling that thread in a while loop in main and want to separate delay of that alien movement and the actual game.

Comment: Hint `std::ref`.

Comment: Take a look of the [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) for creating the thread `t3` which uses passing by the reference.

Comment: It worked. Thanks @karastojko.